# Call qgis function from R?

Tags: qgis, python, r

Is there a package to call QGIS functions directly from R?
Is rPython the best alternative?

Comment: Do you have a specific QGIS function you could give as an example? I'm actually hard-pressed to think of anything QGIS can do that can't be done with native R packages...

Comment: The intersection, spatial request, spatial join and union are really more efficient on QGIS. It's more a question of performance than ability.

Comment: That supposed gain might be lost by rPython converting everything to JSON and back, but it would be a start. A representative example would help with any comparison in finding the best way.